# How to zoom in or zoom out in Google Meet?

Tags: google-meet

In [Google Meet](https://meet.google.com/), when the remote user is having a very large screen, I can hardly see the text.

Is there a way to zoom in/out so a small area is readable?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunatelly, Google Meet does not offer a feature to zoom in a shared screen.

But I had the same problem you described, so I've made a [Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-meet-magnifier/jgbngdlfifppkoggkjpcklnkgkaacbpc) that enables you to do exactly that.

So, if you use Google Chrome and install this extension, you will be able to.

Comment: You, sir, are an absolute GOD! Thanks for that, I have a visual impairment, so this is extremely helpful and very well implemented.

Answer (score 3):

To slightly enlarge the size of the displayed remote screen, go to google meet ... when the video or screen presentation is going on pin that and go to your settings (three vertical dot) of google meet given below with other buttons. Go to layout options and select spotlight that makes the screen a little bigger.

To zoom in the displayed remote screen further, **you can pinch and zoom in too if the screen is touch responsive or if you have a trackpad**.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted. The pinch and zoom is actually really helpful here, since it behaves differently than the "normal" control-[plus/minus] for zooming.  This actually did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Click the pin icon on top of the thumbnail you wish to enlarge.

That's the largest you can get. **Update:** Well, as mentioned in my later comment,  if the remote user shares their browser, they can enlarge it for you with ctrl+.

[image: Google Meet pinicon]

Comment: This still doesn't increase the size as much.

Comment: If the remote user shares their browser, they can enlarge it with ctrl+.

Comment: Ah okay. I will ask in the user to do so next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds ridiculous but join the meeting from your phone as well. on the phone its easy to just 'zoom in' and read anything you want on their screen. Its easy to pinch zoom and pan around with your finger, so much better than the sub par track pad experience that doesnt even work if you laptop is now in a home office dock..

One day Google will add a zoom in and out button like other apps but for now just join the meeting twice and it will probably do exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

### Solution with touchpad (present in most laptops)

Zoom in and out with your two fingers on the touchpad as "pinching gesture". Use your two fingers to move around.